# Sum an array in C, what it should be inserted in the (???) to complete the function?

Tags: c, arrays, sum

```
int arraySum (int array[], int n)  
{  
int sum = 0, *ptr;  
for (ptr = array; ???; ++ptr)  
sum += ???  
return sum;  
}
```

---

**int n** Is the size of the array.

Comment: you probably want to make sure you use the entire array, but no item more.

Comment: First `???`: `0`; second `???`: `0; for (int k=0; k<n; k++) sum += array[k];`

Comment: How about adding a second variable `i` that you increment and make sure that your loop only runs while `i < n`? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems to be your homework / assignment, I'll just give you 2 hints and let it finish you on your own:

**Hint 1**:
When you have a pointer to `int`: `int* ptr`, you can access the `int` it points to by dereferencing your pointer using [dereference operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator): `*ptr`

**Hint 2**:
When you increment `ptr` by `1` 3 times, it will point to the same memory as `ptr + 3` does. Note that `ptr + 3` points to the memory at the address `&ptr[3]`.

Answer (score 0):

The first `???` should be replaced with `ptr < &array[n]`, the second with `*ptr`.

A pointer is an **address in memory**. `array` contains an address (where array[0] is located).

So `array + i` is a pointer to `array[i]`.

You want to travel on the array until you reach the last object, since we're comparing addresses in the `for` loop, so we compare `ptr` with the **address** of the last element in the array. So your program will look:

```
int arraySum (int array[], int n)  
{  
  int sum = 0, *ptr;  
  for (ptr = array; ptr < &array[n]; ++ptr)  
  sum += *ptr;  
  return sum;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int arraySum (int array[], int n)  
{  
  int sum = 0, *ptr;  
  for (ptr = array; ptr - array < n; ++ptr)  
    sum += *ptr;  
  return sum;  
}
```